# Access ModelState from within my custom helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I just want to make a such Helper:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString HasError<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (!ModelState.IsValidField(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)))
            sb.Append("has-error");

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

So the question - how to access to the actual ModelState here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
    foreach (var state in htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState)
    {
        // Do what you what with the ModelState here

        foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
        {
            // Display error here
        }
    }
```